# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'RoomType'

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datalist

i have datatable  i want to filter it to select only the rows when the avalibality not = null,datatable contains null rows i want to select only not null roows from the table,i want to filter the data table because the itemdatabound bind the null rowws it is display in the user interface with null .

```
if (dtRoomDetails != null && dtRoomDetails.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
var expr = "[Availability2] > '0' ";//Availability2 this is the cloumn name i want to select only all values without null values.

dtlRoomsPrice2.DataSource = dtRoomDetails.Select(expr);
dtlRoomsPrice2.DataBind();//error is here when bind data
}
```

```html
<asp:DataList ID="dtlRoomsPrice2" Visible="false" orizontalAlign="center" runat="server"
              ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False" Width="700px" OnItemDataBound="dtlRoomsDetails_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="bordcolrrr">
      <table id="RoomList" style="width: 700px;" border="0" align="left">
        <%

           RowCount++;

           if (UsingRows.IndexOf(RowCount.ToString()) != -1)
           {

           %>
          <tr>
            <td width="215" class="bordercolor" style="">
              <table border="0" id="LeftTable" width="200" align="left">
                <tr>
                  <td  class="shbe_h2" colspan="2" style="position: relative;top: -16px;left: 12px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="Server" CssClass="shbe_label" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.RoomType") %>'
                               Width="170px"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelGr" Visible="false" runat="Server" CssClass="shbe_label" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.GuaranteeRequired") %>'></asp:Label>
                  </td>


                  <td style="width: 55px;">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">
                      <asp:Image Width="60" ID="RoomImg" runat="server" Height="60" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ImageRoomCode") %>' />
                      <span>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" Width="370" Height="246" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ImageRoomCode") %>' /></span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: left;">


                    <asp:Label ID="LblRoomDesc" runat="Server" CssClass="shbe_h2" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.RoomText") %>'
                               Visible="false"></asp:Label>

                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td class="bordercolor" width="100" style="">
              <table border="0" id="singleTbl" class="singtbl" width="70" align="left"  runat="server" style="display: none;">
                <tr>
                  <td width="35"></td>
                  <td class="shbe_h2" style="padding-left: 5px">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSSelect" runat="server" CssClass="btnselect" Text='<%$Resources:Resource,Select %>'
                                CommandName='<%#Eval("IDRoom")+ "-" + Eval("Availability2") %>' CommandArgument="tblBookNow"
                                OnClick="btnSelectRoom_Click2" Visible="false" />

                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%#Eval("IDRoom")+ "-" + Eval("Availability2")%>'></asp:Label>

                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" Width="45px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" >

                    </asp:DropDownList>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="35" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">
                    <br />
                  </td>
                  <td style="padding-left: 10px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSRRate" runat="Server" CssClass="shbe_h2" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.STotalRate2") %>'
                               ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>&nbsp;<span class="shbe_h2" style="display:none;"><%=strCurrency %></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td style="height: 30px; text-align: center">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSRCounter" ForeColor="White" runat="server" BorderStyle="None"
                               BackColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Transparent" CssClass="room-counter" Text="0"
                               Width="36px" Height="29px" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                  </td>
                </tr>
<%} %>
              </table>
```

Comment: Kindly please format your code properly.

Comment: Try `Text='<%# Eval("RoomType") %>'`. but it's not clear how the error message is related to your requirement.

Comment: @un-lucky i formatted the code again

Comment: missing `}` of `if (UsingRows.IndexOf(RowCount.ToString()) != -1)`

Comment: @un-lucky no not missing this }

Comment: @TimSchmelter i tried  Text='<%# Eval("RoomType") %>' still the same error

Comment: @TimSchmelter we can talk on skype or teamviwer if you don't mind to be clear.

Comment: @magdy: you can use LINQ: `dtlRoomsPrice2.DataSource=dtRoomDetails.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("Availability2") != null && int.Parse(r.Field<string>("Availability2"))>1).CopyToDataTable()`

Comment: @TimSchmelter It worked like a charm. thanks alot ., i want to talk with you if you don't mind ??

Comment: @magdy: you can open a chat room if you want. Apart from that i have not the timefor skype of teamviewer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ok we can talk in a chat room

Comment: @TimSchmelter open the chat to talk

Comment: @magdy: i have noticed that you need at lest 20 reputation to chat. Or can you enter it: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86903/magdytim

Comment: i want to improve my skills and problem solving if you references you can help me